# jQuery Click event triggers more times on every window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

People!

This is the first time I come here to ask something, so far, always when I had a problem, I could find a good answer here. So, in first place, thanks for this amazing community!

Now **let's go to the problem:**

I'm doing a responsive menu that check the *window.resize* event and, when it fits the minimum browser width, a click function for a button is allowed. If the browser width is greater, then the click function is unbound. I need to do this because the same element that is the button on the mobile version, is a visual element on the desktop version.

The problem is that, with the code that I have now, when the page is loaded, the click function works fine. But, if I resize the browser and click on the element again, it triggers more than once the state, sometimes leaving the impression that the function isn't triggered. And, if I resize the browser again, it triggers the click function more than the last time I clicked. Really annoying.

To help understand what is happening, I've made a simple example. Here's is the simple code (just to check the click function issue):

## **HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="sub-toggle">Testing 01</span></li>
    <li><span class="sub-toggle">Testing 02</span></li>
    <li><span class="sub-toggle">Testing 03</span></li>
</ul>
```

## **CSS:**

```
.sub-toggle{
    display:block;
    padding: 20px;
}

.sub-toggle.active{
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #fff;
}
```

## **Javascript (jQuery):**

```
jQuery(function($){

    var i = 1;

    // check if browser size is compatible with click event
    onResize = function() {

        // if browser size is ok, do the click function
        if($(window).width() <= 480){

            // click function
            $('.sub-toggle').click(function(){

                alert('click');

                if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                    alert('active');
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }

            });     

        } else{
            // if browser size is greater than expected, unbind the click function
            $('.sub-toggle').removeClass('active').unbind('click');
        }

        // just checking how many times the resize function is triggered 
        console.log('resize: '+ i);
        i++;

    }

    $(document).ready(onResize);

    var timer;

    $(window).bind('resize', function(){
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(onResize, 500);
    });

});
```

**(Edited to remove some unnecessary code)**

If you want to see it in action, I've made a Fiddle (try resize the output frame to see it working): http://jsfiddle.net/C7ppv/1/

Maybe I've missing something really stupid, since I don't have a huge knowledge in JavaScript. But **what I want to do is just trigger the click event once**, even if multiple resizes.

I hope I could explain well my problem. I've searched and didn't found a solution for this issue (or maybe I just didn't know really well what to look for).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hy, Nathan! Thanks for your response! Sorry, but I'm not sure if I understood your suggestion. Could you tell me more about it? You are talking about the **onResize** function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `resize` event is triggered multiple times during resizing, and each time you're binding a new click handler. My suggestion: bind only once, from outside the resize handler, and set a flag while resizing to let the click handler know if it should do something or not.

Then you won't even need to defer the handling of `resize` with `setTimeout` as you're doing.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWCF3/)

```
jQuery(function($){

    var i = 1;

    // flag to allow clicking
    var clickAllowed = true;

    // click function
    $('.sub-toggle').click(function(){
        if(clickAllowed) {
            alert('click');

            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                alert('active');
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        }
    }); 

    // check if browser size is compatible with click event
    onResize = function() {

        //if browser size is ok, do the click function
        if($(window).width() <= 480){
            clickAllowed = true;
        }
        else{
            // if browser size is greater than expected, disallow clicking
            clickAllowed = false;

        }

        // just checking how many times the resize function is triggered 
        console.log('resize: '+ i);
        i++;

    }

    $(document).ready(onResize);

    var timer;
    $(window).bind('resize', onResize);
});
```

Comment: Hy, @bfavaretto! The answer from Ruben Infante worked for me, but this looks a better approach, not to the previous answer, but to the code itself. Instead of trigger the unbind everytime before the click event, it just looks for the `clickAllowed` variable and do the code only when it's true. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: I'm glad to help! Note that all answers here should work, and are valid approaches (Ruben's is possibly more computationally intensive, though).

Comment: Actually, ethagnawl's answer sounds like the simplest: you don't even need an onresize handler, just check for the widths when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Your're right about it, maybe I'll check later his approach and check which one performs better.

Answer (score 7):

Your code currently binds a new `click` events every time the method `onResize` is called and the window width is less than or equal to `480px`.

Simply unbind any existing `click` events on the `.sub-toggle` element before binding a new one.

```
$('.sub-toggle').unbind('click').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YYKwp/)**

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm! Like I said, it was something simple that my knowledge of Javascript and jQuery didn't  reached. I've spend hours to figure it out, and a couple minutes here on StackOverflow took me to the answer! Thanks, Ruben Infante!

Comment: @DiegodeOliveira No problem. For what may be a better overall solution, I would suggest looking at bfavaretto's answer as well.

Comment: I agree, I've checked his answer and his approach looks better for the code itself. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! So simple! That I didn’t thought about that! Resolved also my re-attachable window resize functionality when new ajax content inserted! Thanks man!

Comment: Much better than using a timeout, thank you very much +1

Answer (score 2):

Move `$('.sub-toggle').click(function(){...}` outside the onResize event handler and move `if($(window).width() <= 480){...}` into the click handler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @ethagnawl! Like @bfavaretto said on his comment, this way I don't even need the onResize handler. I like his approach, but I think I would test yours later and check which one performs better with the real code I'm using.